# Flagging Method on checking string

Tags: c, loops

I have a question about checking method in C. If I have a string for example : `char name[100] = "summma";` How to check if that string has the same character or not with flagging method?

I tried this : I scanned the length of summa using `strlen(name)` and I loop it with `for`. After that, I use `if` to check the same characters. But I only can check the same characters if that character is next to each other.

```
int x,y,z,i,j,k,l,testcase;
char kalimat[100];
char checkarray[400];

scanf("%d",&testcase); getchar();

for(int i = 0; i < testcase; i++) {
    gets(kalimat);
    int len = strlen(kalimat);

    int count = 0;
    for(int j = 0; j < len; j++) {
        if(kalimat[j] == kalimat[j+1]) {
            count++;
        }
    }
    printf("%d\n",count );
    if(count > 0) {
        printf("Yes\n");
    } else{
        printf("No\n");
    }
}
```

But, the problem is, it wont detect the character like this : "abbcb"

Comment: "has the same character" you mean "has repeated characters"?

Comment: Also, since it looks like you're learning, take the good habit of *never using `gets`*.

Comment: @Felix Prima What is the flagging method?

Comment: Please explain you problem in more specific details

Comment: So you mean that a string like `sala` should be counted because it has two `a` in it? Then the naive and simple method would be a loop within a loop.

Comment: `unsigned flags[UCHAR_MAX + 1] = {0}; for (unsigned k = 0; k < strlen(kalimat); k++) flags[(unsigned char)kalimat[k]]++; for (unsigned k = 0; k <= UCHAR_MAX) if (flags[k] >= 2) printf("%c appears %u times\n", (int)k, flags[k]);`

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude yes like that.

Answer (score -1):

What you could do is having an array with a number for each character(26 if only using from A to Z, 256 if using all ASCII symbols) and each time you read a char you add 1 to its corresponding number in the array. When you finish reading all the chars you check if any number is greater than one:

```
int main() {
  char kalimat[100];
  scanf("%s", kalimat);
  int characters[256] = {0}; // 26 if using only A-Z
  int len = strlen(kalimat);
  for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    characters[kalimat[i]]++;
    // If only using A-Z:
    // characters[kalimat[i]-'A']++;
    // and if using a-z:
    // characters[kalimat[i]-'a']++;
  }
  for (int i = 0; i < 256; i++) { // 26 if A-Z
    if (characters[i] > 1) {
      printf("'%c' has been repeated %d times.\n", (char)i, characters[i]);
    }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: ```char c = 'a'``` try to access ```kalimat[c]``` with an array of size 26 and you're gonna have a bad time...

Comment: @JohnSmith It would be `kalimat[c-'a']`in that case but you are right that it is not guaranteed to work that way.

Comment: @Gerhardh yeah but i mean, this just doesn't work. Yes it does tell you if a letter is repeated but you waste a lot of space (256 ints to actually use only 52) and if you have a mix of lowercase and uppercase letters you either distinguish between them to subtract the value or you can end up printing the wrong character in the ```printf``` (E.G. subtract 'A' = 65 from 'c' = 99 you get 34 which is ") and even worse the other way around. Not mentioning that it's even slower than just having a double loopiterating twice on the string...